# Is there a symbol for inverse proportionality?

Tags: inverse

As the title said, is there a symbol for, or group of symbols for, Inverse Proportionality. I know that the symbol for proportionality is ∝, but I am having difficulty finding one for inverse proportionality.

Comment: You don't need one. If $a$ is inversely proportional to $b$, $$a∝\frac1b$$

Comment: @ajay The whole point of the $∝$ symbol is that the proportionality constant is left implicit.

Comment: Oh...I was taught to write it as follows $a ∝ \frac{k}{b}$ for some constant $k$.